# My view controller file is too long, how to put some functions in a separate swift file

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have PlayViewController.swift and it has simply gotten too long.
I added a new swift file "Options.swift" and cut-pasted some of the functions from PlayViewController.swift to the Options.swift

Now when I run the project, it give 'Use of unresolved identifier ' error on function calls

Also any calls to ui items in playcontroller with with self. give 'use of unresolved identifier 'self'

what am i missing?

Comment: Well, `self` is only valid in a class, so if you rip out some methods and move it to another file (thereby making it functions) `self` becomes undefined. And the places where you call the methods that are now functions can't be resolved since the compiler doesn't know where the definitions are. Without seeing code, this is a bit of a guessing game though. If you post your code, the community can give far more accurate help quicker.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want to do is write an *[extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH24-XID_229)* to PlayViewController in your other file. So, the other file will look like this:

```
extension PlayViewController {
    // ... stick your functions (i.e. methods) here
}
```

This use of an extension, as a way of spreading a class's definition over more than one file, is perfectly legitimate and common.

Comment: Although take notice that you cannot declare properties in Swift extensions (unless use `objc_setAssociatedObject`), which is slightly annoying to me, when I want to break a huge class declaration.