# Xcode lagging in large swift files

Tags: swift, xcode6, lag, xcode6.1

Why does Xcode lag in large files and does anyone know how to stop this?

I have a .swift file which is 8,000+ lines of code and when I try to modify the file Xcode changes my cursor into a beachball and lags.

Does anyone know why this happens or how to fix it without breaking the file up into smaller pieces?

Comment: Do you have a specific reason for not wanting to break the code up into multiple files? Having 8,000 lines of code in a single file is highly indicative of poor design.

Comment: Though I concur with @maxint you find threads on Apple Developer forums where they discuss the slowness of Swift with large files. You probably my turn off auto-compilation.

Comment: I actually don't have a very good reason other than the fact that the code is being generated by a code generator. I would've just liked to know why this happens.

Comment: Yes, It is poor design. But still Xcode is probably one of the most advanced IDEs and should not have issues like this. Maybe for whatever reason this might be necessary. Have a nice day.

Comment: Yes, you should probably break that up if you can. But even still, Xcode has tons of problems when it comes to normal app-scale projects. I've currently got 25k LOC in my Swift code in my project, and it takes >4 minutes to compile on a 2012 MBP running OS X 10.9.5.

Comment: Is it a Swift problem or just a problem with Xcode? Correct me if I am wrong, but there wasn't that many problems while coding in Objective-C.

Comment: That is unacceptable, hopefully this will be fixed in the near future.

Comment: When the first XCode6 Beta came out, I had the same problem with .swift files not larger than 1000 lines. Swift support in XCode improved since then and will further improve in the future.

Comment: @PetriOosthuizen what are the specs of your computer? how much RAM? what OS is it running? Do you have any other applications open while using Xcode? Are any other users logged in?

Comment: @Developer_ACE - I have a mid 2012 MacBook Pro, 4GB Ram, 2,3 GHz Intel Core i7, an SSD and Intel HD Graphics 4000 1024 MB. Yes, most of the time I do have other applications open such as Safari, Chrome, Eclipse, the simulator (obviously), mail, iTunes and Terminal. I have tried closing these apps but it doesn't help. Also I have OSX 10.10.2.

Comment: Have you tried getting more RAM?

Comment: I have this problem too. I don't think it's a problem with RAM. my Macbook Air mid 2014, 4GB Ram. 1.3 Core i5. new SSD. I still have 1.2GB available when Xcode lagging with big swift file. I think it's XCode's bug.

Comment: Everyone at Apple uses Mac Pro 12-core workstations with 1GB/sec. SSD and 128 GB RAM. It's your own fault for trying to do professional work on 3-year-old hardware!!! lolololol sucka

Comment: Have you tried using **extensions**? <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27591844/my-view-controller-file-is-too-long-how-to-put-some-functions-in-a-separate-swi> (Posting this here for people that might come from google search)

Answer (score 1):

**The last versions of Xcode are "buggy"**, specially with *SourceKit*.

Be aware that [Swift is a *type safe* language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID322) and every time you modify something, the project code is re-analyzed.
Because of that and the combination of your large app, this may be the cause of your issue.

in addition, verify that your hardware specs are "ok" for development (it may be simple as to free up memory, or may involve to upgrade your hardware)

**These issues may be resolved** in *Xcode 6.3* + *Swift 1.2*.

Hope this lighted :)

Answer (score -3):

Get a top of the line Mac Pro with 1-gig-per-second SSD and 64 GB RAM. Or better yet build a hackintosh and overclock the CPU to 7 GHZ. Problem solved.